# Java Lambda expression stream two maps with same keys and a list of different objects

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have two Maps :

```
Map<A, List<B>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
```

And

```
Map<A, List<C>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
```

Where C is a nested object in B, like this:

```
public class B {

private C c;

}
```

I want to filter in map1 to exclude all entries with same keys in map2 and `A from map1` = `A from map2` and `B.C in map1` = `C in map2`

So the result will be:

```
Map<A, List<B>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: And can you give an example of input and expected output?

Comment: A statement of wishes is not a question. Please [edit] your question and include a full problem description, including (a) example input and expected output, (b) your own attempt to solve the issue, and (c) an explanation of where you got stuck - if an error, the stack trace. If a wrong output - the wrong output.

Comment: Thanks for telling us - if that's what you want to do, then go ahead. (There isn't a question being asked.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? using [Collection#removeIf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) to remove all of `A` entries from `map1`, if the `C` of `B` contains in `map2` in an entry.

```
map1.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> entry.getValue().stream().anyMatch(
        b -> map2.getOrDefault(entry.getKey(), emptyList()).contains(b.c)
));
```

**OR** using [Stream#filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) instead.

```
Map<A, List<B>> result = map1.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().stream().noneMatch(
            b -> map2.getOrDefault(entry.getKey(), emptyList()).contains(b.c)
    ))
    .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: Using Stream#filter works fine. thank you for your help

Comment: @Mohamed Not at all.